# gclient sync webrtc for android 'No output for xxx seconds from command'

Tags: android, git, webrtc

I want to use webrtc for android through native , there is a problem always when I command "gclient sync --nohooks". The log text is 'No output for xxx seconds from command:
    git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress --template=/Users/moushou/depot_tools/git-templates https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools.git /Users/moushou/trunk/third_party/_gclient_android_tools_38zdCb;  cwd=/Users/moushou'. Please help me , thank you very much.